# Intellij Idea "Reset current branch to here" usage

Tags: git

I'm on local branch A, and I've pushed 3 commits to origin/A. Those commits break stuff so I want to remove them completely. From the Git:Log tab of Intellij Idea I moved to Branch:origin/A, right-clicked the last commit before the first of the 3 and I've given "Reset current branch to here" selecting Hard reset as option.

But I can still see the commits in the Git:Log tab and if I pull I get those 3 commits again... how can I remove them completely from origin?

Comment: You need to push to the target. And since it's not a fast-forward push (quite the opposite, actually), you may need to force-push.

Answer (score 1):

If you have pushed the commit to remote already you need to select "revert commit" instead of "reset current branch to here".

You can find a detailed instructions here: [Revert a pushed commit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/undo-changes.html#revert-commit)

[image]

For the case that you just want to undo your local commits than choose "Undo commit"